# How to dismiss the ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I am facing the issue in dismissing the `ProgressDialog`. When I replace the fragment with another fragment in a container, the fragment is calling twice and ProgressDialog` is not dismissing.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
.setTitle("Transfer Status")
.setMessage(msg)
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("number", mobNumber);
        args.putString("rno", rnoValue);
        args.putInt("count",1);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(Fragment_New_Money_Transfer.class.getSimpleName(),
        FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        Fragment_New_Money_Transfer fragment = new Fragment_New_Money_Transfer();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        //     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment_Money_Transfer.class.getSimpleName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}).show();
```

The above code is for replacing the fragment.

The below code is for loading and dismissing dialog

```
public ProgressDialog loadProgressDialoges() {
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
    pDialog.isIndeterminate();
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    return pDialog;
}

public void dismissProgressDialog(ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
//     pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Please help me how to solve this.

This is my function calling the progress dialog

```
public void getTransferList(){
  showProgress();
        Ion.with(this)
                .load(HelperClass.SERVER_ID + HelperClass.postApis+"/mtvaliatemobileno")
                .setTimeout(HelperClass.timeOut)
                . setHeader(HelperClass.authName,authToken)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.contentName,HelperClass.contentValue)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.secretKeyName,newEncryptedSecretNumber)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.apiKeyName,encryptedDeviceId)
                .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                .asJsonObject()
                .withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                        dismissDialog();
                        if (e != null) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            if (result != null) {

                                try{
                                    Boolean responceMessage = result.getResult().get("res").getAsBoolean();

                                    JsonObject jsonObject1 = result.getResult().get("CardDetail").getAsJsonObject();
}
}
}
```

The below code is for show and dismiss progress dialog

```
 public void showProgress() {
    if (pDialog == null) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    }
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
public void dismissDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I have declared the ProgressDialog Globally.

Answer (score -1):

You have create new instance for `ProgressDialog` so now there is two ProgressDialog. And also you inside `loadProgressDialoges()` you have created it as locally so there is no way you can dismiss it.

**Solution**;- Just use a Single instance globally .

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public void showProgress() {
        if (pDialog == null) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    }
    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: If you use above code then it should be dismiss . Do not create `ProgressDialog` locally .

Comment: When i came continiously came  back to this fragment,first time progress dialog is dismissed , when in second time dialog is not dismissed.

Comment: My issue is when i came back to same fragment for two times means , first time dialog is dismissed, second time dialog is not dismissed.

Comment: You have messed up somewhere with life cycle.

Comment: you are right, but i don't know why the issue is occurring and how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure you calling showProgress() only once ? And any other `ProgressDialog` not created ?